# How can I read a Base64 file that comes as a chain?

Tags: java, base64

I am currently developing a REST service which receives in its request a field where it is passed a file in base 64 format ("n" characters come). What I do within the service logic is to convert that character string to a File to save it in a predetermined path.

But the problem is that when the file is too large (3MB) the service becomes slow and takes a long time to respond.

This is the code I am using:

```java
String filename = "TEXT.DOCX"
BufferedOutputStream stream = null;
// THE FIELD base64file IS WHAT A STRING IN BASE FORMAT COMES FROM THE REQUEST 64
byte [] fileByteArray = java.util.Base64.getDecoder (). decode (base64file);
// VALID FILE SIZE
if ((1 * 1024 * 1024 <fileByteArray.length) {
    logger.info ("The file [" + filename + "] is too large");
} else {
    stream = new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (new File ("C: \" + filename)));
    stream.write (fileByteArray);
}
```

How can I do to avoid this inconvenience. And that my service does not take so long to convert the file to File.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering does not improve your performance here, as all you are trying to do is simply write the file as fast as possible. Generally it looks fine, change your code to directly use the FileOutputStream and see if it betters things:

```
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
    stream.write(bytes);
}
```

Alternatively you could also try using something like Apache Commons to do the task for you:

FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path), bytes);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, also for large files.

```
Path outPath = Paths.get(filename);
try (InputStream in = Base64.getDecoder ().wrap(base64file)) {
    Files.copy(in, outPath);
}
```

This keeps only a buffer in memory. Your code might become slow because of taking more memory.

`wrap` takes an InputStream which you should provide, not the entire String.

Answer (score 0):

From Network point of view:
Both json and xml can support large amount of data exchange. And, 3MB is not really huge. But, there is a limitation on how much browser can handle (if this call is from a user interface). 
Also, web server like Tomcat has property to handle 2MB by default (check maxPostSize http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)

You can also try chunking the request payload (although it shouldn't be required for a 3MB file)

From Implementation point of view:
Write operation on your disk could be slow. It also depends on your OS.
If your file size is really large, you can use Java FileChannel class with ByteBuffer.

To know the cause of slowness (network delay or code), check the performance with a simple Java program against the web service call.